# Python,join() function, adding space between words

Tags: python, function

I need to write a function that takes two strings (text and word) and returns the text with the chosen word replaced with asterisks (the number of asterisks should correspond to the number of letters in the censored word.).

For example:

if text="hey hey hey" and word="hey" the returned text should be:

```
'*** *** ***'
```

Here is my code:

```
def censor(text,word):
    text = text.split(" ")
    asterisks=[]
    text_with_asterisks=[]

    for item in text:
        if item not in word:
            text_with_asterisks.append(item)
        else:
            asterisks=[]
            for letter in word:
                asterisks.append("*")

            text_with_asterisks.append(' '.join(asterisks))
    return (" ".join(text_with_asterisks))
```

The code works but it returns:

```
 *********
```

and not

```
*** *** ***.
```

Once I use the line:

```
return ("_".join(text_with_asterisks))
```

instead I get:

```
'***_***_***'
```

I don't understand why the "  " is ignored and how can I add a space between the words.

Thanks!

Comment: I get `* * * * * * * * *`

Comment: I am not getting the same result as you.  I am getting `'* * * * * * * * *`.  This is due to the `text_with_asterisks.append(' '.join(asterisks))` line.  If I change the `' '` there to `''`, I get `'*** *** ***'`.

Comment: You can multiply strings: `'*' * len(word)`

Comment: You have to use `join` twice, first to join the asterisks that replace each word which, then again to join the asterisk replaced words. Which you have done, *but* you need to first time use `""` as separator and the next time use `" "` as separator.

Comment: In addition your code does not do what you might expect. It's actually looking for words that are a part of the `word`. Calling `cencor("he", "hey")` you'll get `***` because `he` is a part of `hey` and three asterisk because `hey` has three letters.

Comment: The first part of your message suggests that there is a single word that you want to replace but your example program seems to imply that you actually have a list of words you want to censor. Maybe you should make that clear. Otherwise, clever one liners like Adem Öztaş' are probably what you want.

Comment: TheBlackCat- Thanks! It worked!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra space when you join your asterisks:

```
def censor(text, word):
    text = text.split(" ")
    asterisks=[]
    text_with_asterisks=[]

    for item in text:
        if item not in word:
            text_with_asterisks.append(item)
        else:
            asterisks=[]
            for letter in word:
                asterisks.append("*")

            text_with_asterisks.append(''.join(asterisks)) #here's the culprit
    return (" ".join(text_with_asterisks))
```

`censor("hey hey hey", "hey")` outputs what you want (`'*** *** ***'`)

I just pointed out your mistake, but surely there's a more elegant and efficient way to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works just fine now.
Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use Regex method or alike but I do agree there is more elegant way to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simplest solution

```
text.replace(word, "*" * len(word))
```

Comment: This will also replace the word if it is part of another word, e.g. it will replace "ass" in "masses". Better use regex with word boundary markers.

Comment: text.replace(" " + word + " " , "*" * len(word))  - doest it help?

Comment: What about punctuation then?

Answer (score 3):

Regex method of doing this -

```
import re
def censor(text,word):
    return re.sub(r'\b(?i){0}\b'.format(re.escape(word)),'*' * len(word), text)
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> censor('hey hey they hey','hey')
'*** *** they ***'

>>> censor('hey hey they Hey','hey')
'*** *** they ***'
```

Comment: How about `(?i)` for making it case-insensitive and `re.escape(word)`? Otherwise, exactly what I just wanted to post.

Comment: Done - `re.sub(r'\b(?i){0}\b'.format(re.escape(word)),'*' * len(word), text)`

Answer (score 2):

You have spaces between every `*` in the word, and additional spaces between the words, so I think, you only want spaces between words:

```
def censor(text, word):
    return ' '.join('*'*len(word) if word==item else item for item in text.split())
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution,

```
>>> text = "hey hey hey"
>>> "***".join(text.split("hey"))
'*** *** ***'
```

Or

```
 >>> text = "hey hey they Hey','hey"  
 >>> " ".join([ '***' if word.lower() == 'hey' else word
 ... for word in text.replace("'","").replace(","," ").split()])
 '*** *** they *** ***'
```

Answer (score 1):

As `text_with_asterisks.append(' '.join(asterisks))` does, each character is joined by `" "`, and then `" ".join(text_with_asterisks)` also makes each words joined by `" "`, thus the output is: `* * * * * * * * *`, where there is a space between each star.

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(text, censor_w):
    splitted_text = text.split(" ")
    asterics = "*" * len(censor_w)
    result = []

    for word in splitted_text:
        if word == censor:
            result.append(asterics)
        else:
            result.append(word)

    return " ".join(result)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.